# I²C frequency changeable?

Tags: i2c

Is the I²C frequency meanwhile changeable? I read a few articles a while ago, that the frequency is not changeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, for all the info available on the I2C interface (which is part of the BSC, Broadcom Serial Controller), I suggest reading Chapter 3 (BSC) of the [BCM2835 ARM Peripherals datasheets](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf).

On the first page of Chapter 3, it mentions the *Clock Divider* register. On page 33, it explains this register in more depth:

> Clock Divider
>
> SCL = core clock / CDIV
>
> Where core_clk is nominally 150 MHz. If CDIV is
> set to 0, the divisor is 32768. CDIV is always
> rounded down to an even number. The default
> value should result in a 100 kHz I2C clock
> frequency.

Comment: The core clock seems to 250 rather than 150 MHz at least on the Raspberry Pi Zero W.

Answer (score 2):

[i2cf](https://github.com/un-clouded/rpi-stuff/blob/master/i2cf/i2cf.c) is a small tool to change the I2C clock frequency.

Changes to 10 kHz and 4 kHz were verified with an oscilloscope.  Tested only on a Raspberry Pi Zero W.  The source may require modification for other models or to be a more generic solution.